# Is it wise to do event binding in the prototype & why is the context of this lost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, jquery-events

When creating modular JavaScript code for web pages, I often need to attach events to e.g. buttons.

Take the following *example code*, typically found in an AMD module:

```
define(function(require) {

    var MyObject = function(ele) {
        this.ele = ele;
    }

    MyObject.prototype = {
        myfunct: function() {
            console.log('myfunct called');
        }
    }

    return MyObject;

});
```

Later on the page I would do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#button'),
        myobj = new MyObject(button);

    button.click(function() {
        myobj.myfunct();
    });
});
```

This works, but still seems to be a bit unclean I think.

For example, I need to create at least one variable in the global namespace to bind a function to a button. Also, when there are many JavaScript powered interactions on a page, the code gets messy – which is something I initially wanted to tackle by using modular JavaScript.

Thats why my idea was to to the event binding inside the prototype:

```
var MyObject = function(ele) {
    self = this;
    this.element = ele; 

    this.init();
}

MyObject.prototype = {
    init: function() {        
        $(this.element).click(function() {
           self.myfunct();
        });
    },
    myfunct: function() {
        console.log('myfunct called');
    }
}
```

That way, the code outside of the module would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#button'),
        myobj = new MyObject(button);

});
```

**Is it wise to move the event binding into the prototype? If so, is it okay the way I have done it, or is there a way using `init()`?**

In addition, I've noticed that when there are two buttons on a page, some context is lost – `self` always refer to the last instance of `MyObj`.

**Why is this happening – I thought with using `self = this;` I could prevent the context?**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uormpzce/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first what's happening with `self`.

With this line:

```
self = this;
```

you are creating a global variable called `self` that gets overwritten every time your constructor is called. This could have been easily detected if you were using strict mode. Also, if you were using a local variable correctly, your prototype would have no idea what `self`, so you attempt to use `self` in the prototype is broken.

I think there are problems with both of your approaches:

- The first approach requires too much manual work *outside* of your MyObject type.
- The second approach (if it worked correctly) attaches events to the button as a side effect of calling the constructor. This is confusing to someone using your API because one expects a constructor to create an object, not to modify other existing objects.

As a remedy, I would propose the following approach:

```
var MyObject = function(ele) {
    this.element = ele; 
}

MyObject.prototype = {
    attachEvents: function() {        
        var self = this;
        $(this.element).click(function() {
           self.myfunct();
        });
    },
    myfunct: function() {
        console.log('myfunct called');
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#button'),
        myobj = new MyObject(button);

    myobj.attachEvents();
});
```

This requires one extra step on the part of the person instantiating the `MyObject`, but it clearly conveys the intent of attaching events to `myobj`'s encapsulated elements. It also doesn't require someone using a `MyObject` to do the intricate maneuvering of your first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the second question. The problem with your code is that you declare `self` as global variable because you forgot/omitted `var` keyword. As the result when you create two or more instances the last one overwrites previous and `self` inside all click events points to the last instance.

Check the fixed code. Note that you have to move `var self = this` to init method, because now it's local variable:

```
var MyObject = function(ele) {
    this.element = ele; 
    this.init();
}

MyObject.prototype = {
    init: function() {        
        var self = this;
        $(this.element).click(function() {
           self.myfunct();
        });
    },
    myfunct: function() {
        console.log('myfunct called');
    }
}
```

As for the first question, it's alright it's your design and there is nothing wrong with it. Binding events in `init` method is indeed cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with doing the event binding the way you are. The reason you're losing the scope is because you did

```
self = this;
```

which created self as a global variable, in the constructor function. So every time you call the constructor it sets self to that instance.

To fix it, set self as a local variable in your init function:

```
MyObject.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    var self = this;  // <-- this is the fix      
    $(this.element).click(function() {
       self.myfunct();
    });
}
```